# What is this strange long wire for in a single induction cooking unit?

Tags: safety, wiring, mains

Tonight I dismantled one of those single induction hobs:

[image: Prolectrix Induction Hob]

Inside there were two PCBs. The incoming mains was wired to the top left PCB, while the other contained all the low voltage components, plus some more high voltage parts.

[image: Inside induction hob]

There are two white wires connecting the two PCBs. One is short, as you would expect. The other is much longer, and part of it is covered in heat proof braid, and is held down by a loop of metal.

What is the reason for this piece of wire being so much longer and covered in heatproof braid?

Comment: @m.Alin - Why did you remove my nice new tags ?

Comment: Who's ever gonna use again 'induction-hob'?

Comment: What the hell is the `white-goods` tag for? It sounds like some sort of creepy-ass "white man's burden" thing.

Comment: @FakeName - [White Goods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Major_appliance) is a british term which refers to those large white electrical appliances in your house, fridge, dishwasher, etc.

Comment: I had something like that (two white wires with a blob in the middle) connected to stove controller and it turned out to be a heat-sensitive, single-use fuse. (My wife blocked off the heat escape vent on top stove surface by the electric coils and the fuse went.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My guess is that there is a thermistor or other heat sensor under the braid.  This sensor could be used as a safety device to prevent a fire if the temperature gets too high.  It might even just be a thermal link that melts if it gets too hot and removes power from the hob.

Comment: I removed the metal but was not able to remove the braid. I didn't want to cut it. It feels like there's a component in there. I wonder if it's a resettable fuse?

Comment: Probably a non-resettable fuse like you find in a coffee maker.

Answer (score 4):

I saw this in my electric fryer. It is a thermal fuse. It is non-resettable. My thermal fuse in the electric fryer was burnt once, I just by-passed it and it worked OK. But normally you should replace it if it is burnt.

Comment: Strange. Why not just use a normal fuse then? Why go to all the trouble? Can it really be cheaper ?

Comment: @Rocketmagnet, a thermal fuse is used to shut off the device when it is overheated *by an external source*. A normal fuse shuts off when it is overheated by self-heating. Obviously either fuse will fail no matter where the heat comes from, but a thermal fuse will be hooked up so as not to produce much self-heating, and an electrical fuse may be designed to be thermally isolated from its environment (to maximize self-heating). So they aren't interchangeable.

Comment: @ThePhoton - Gotcha!

Comment: I destroyed a radio by applying the wrong voltage.  Someone had bypassed the fuse!